# How do I output a CSV using PowerShell without the "#TYPE" line?

Tags: powershell

this is sort of related to another post.  I've got the following script written:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'DC=aaaa,DC=com' | Export-CSV "ADUsers.csv"
```

This outputs a CSV file but at the first row of the file reads:

```
#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser"
```

This is messing up SSIS when it tries to read it.  Is there any way of not adding that first line?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Add the `NoTypeInformation` switch, like this:

```
Export-Csv "../SSIS/Import Data/ADUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
Export-Csv "../SSIS/Import Data/ADUsers.csv" -NoType
```

Comment: Not really a different answer. All parameters can be written using incomplete names as long as there are enough characters to make it unique. So you could use `-not` if you want as the only other similar parameter is `-NoClobber`. Considering we have tab-completion in PS (and intellisense in ISE) to help us write fast and correct, answers here and scripts in general should avoid shortcuts.