# How to not show/export the first row on CSV file export-csv, Azure, powershell,

Tags: csv, powershell, azure

Good Afternoon,

After I executed this, for example

```
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer | export-csv -Path "C:\Users\meme\Desktop\AzureProject\3-Month Free Trial-SQLDataServer.csv"
```

The result of CSV is
first row shows

> "#TYPE
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Model.SqlDatabaseServerContext"

then second row is

A2=Administration,B2=Location,C2=Version,D2=State,E2=Severname,F2=Operation,G2=OperationStatus

I do not need the first row, I want the second row to be the first row,

How can I program powershell like second row would be the first row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I output a CSV using PowerShell without the "#TYPE" line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547923/how-do-i-output-a-csv-using-powershell-without-the-type-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That commented line is a type annotation that PowerShell can use later do "recreate" objects from the csv.

You can use the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter with [`Export-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) to avoid it:

```
$Path =  "C:\Users\meme\Desktop\AzureProject\3-Month Free Trial-SQLDataServer.csv"
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I would like to click "up", but I do not have 15 reputations therefore, I can not do that, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, click the tickmark under the up/down arrows to "accept" it